# How can I get the networking to work offline for a Debian VirtualBox VM in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, debian

So I am running a Debian VirtualBox VM in Mac OS X. If I am connected to internet through wifi or ethernet everything works just fine in the Bridged Adapter mode. But how can I get it to work offline too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a host-only network on the host (Preferences > Network). You can choose the ip address range used by this network and you can also activate a DHCP server.

Then, in the VM configuration you need to add a card, choose “Host-only networking” and select the network you just created.

Boot the VM and it will have a new interface. You need to configure that interface either with a static IP or by using DCHP if you started the server on the host.

More documentation : [Host-only networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)